# How to tailor existing MongoDB peacefully?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, nosql

Supose i have a running mongodb instance(also using mongo sharding) with millions of data and thousand of transactions per second, and i have used morphia as my object-document mappe.
since we want to keep project alive by bug fixing, updating and ... in some point changing the data model will be inevitable. consider below example : 
I have a persisted class (model) :

```
private EventAsset{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String time;
    private EventType eventType;
}
```

and now we have decided that the EventAsset.class should change to :

```
private EventAsset{
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String time;
    @Constraints.Required
    private String assetName;
}
```

as you can see `eventType` has been removed and Required `assetName` is added, and this changes will prevent application from starting. The only major possible solutions that i can think of are

- Create a new db and insert the old values into it and some how manage
  to switch between old and new db in a way that you wont harm
  incomming few thousant transactions per second.
- Use or create a tool that will analyse your class and compare it
  against the database and make the necessary changes to existing db
  and cause no harm to exisitng data and incomming data flow (few
  thousant transaction per second)

This scenario seems to be an every day (or at least every few months or so) problem to every live project. so is there an accepted solution for this problem? what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Removing `@Constraints.Required` shouldn't be a problem and adding a new attribute is fine as well. Your app won't start because of `@Constraints.Required` — ist that an annotation from the Play framework?

I'd think this requirement is pretty much the same in relational databases as well — add a new column, make it required, and it won't work any longer.

Possible solutions I'd see:

- Drop the annotation and only enforce that logic for new writes in your application
- Have some cleanup application that adds the value to existing data (if that's possible). Add the annotation once the value exists on all entries.
- Use multiple datastores if you must — not sure if this is worth the overhead. And use at least Morphia 1.0.0-rc0, because there has been a bug before with multiple datastores in a single application.

Comment: removing the eventType will cause problem. the goal of this investigation is to come up with a solution to keep your database backward and forward compatible

Comment: If you still need to read but not write the attribute, use MongoDB's annotation `@NotSaved`. If you want to drop the field in all documents: `db.event.update({},{$unset: {eventType:1}}, {multi: true})`